# Java streams: transforming map's values

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, stream

Having an instance of a `Map<A, Set<B>>` where `B` is a POJO with property `Integer price` (among others), how do I elegantly transform this map into a `Map<A, Integer>` where `Integer` denotes the sum of `prices` of a given set, for each key `A`?

Comment: @Michael That's not very helpful comment. I know how to solve it with explicit loop, I'm not sure about streams.

Comment: @weno then show your attempt with loops. That way it is quite easy to create a stream solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stream like this:

```
Map<A, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, 
                b -> b.getValue().stream()
                        .mapToInt(B::getPrice)
                        .sum()
                ));
```

Answer (score -2):

That should help you out. Using the Streaming-API from Java 8:
(In this example the class "PricePojo" is your B and "String" is your A)

```
 Map<String, Integer> newMap = map.entrySet().stream()//
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(PricePojo::getPrice).sum()));
```

You could also go the way of implementing a Map.Entry yourself like in the following example:

```
    Map<String, Integer> newMap = map.entrySet().stream()//
    .map(entry -> new Map.Entry<String, Integer>() {
    private int sum = entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(PricePojo::getPrice).sum();
    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return entry.getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer setValue(Integer value) {
        return sum = value.intValue();
    }
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```